The derivation of the Fourier transform formula for functions on R
Assuming that Fourier's representation of function as a sum/integral of complex exponentials is valid, we can write a function $s:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ as
$$
\begin{equation*}
s(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{s}(t) e^{i 2 \pi \xi t}d\xi
\end{equation*}
$$
and a function $r:\mathbb{T}_p\to\mathbb{C}$ as
$$
\begin{equation*}
r(t) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{r}(k) e^{i 2 \pi k / p t}.
\end{equation*}
$$
Now, one can easily verify that
$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\langle e^{i 2 \pi n t}, r(t) \rangle &= \int_{\mathbb{T}_p} e^{-i 2 \pi n t} r(t)dt \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{T}_p} e^{-i 2 \pi n t} \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{r}(k) e^{i 2 \pi k / p t}dt \\
&= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{r}(k) \int_{\mathbb{T}_p} e^{i 2 \pi (k - n) / p t}dt \\
&= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{r}(k) p \delta_{k,n} \\
&= p\hat{r}(n),
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$
where the exponential $e^{i 2 \pi (k-n) / p t}$ rotates $k-n$ times around
the unit circle when $t$ goes from $0$ to $p$, and thus averages out to zero
for $t \in \mathbb{T}_p$ unless $k=n$ in which case it averages out to $p$, since it doesn't rotate at all and stays at $1$.
So, in another words, the Fourier transform of $r$ is given by the familiar formula
$$
\begin{equation*}
\hat{r}(n) = \frac{1}{p} \langle e^{i 2 \pi n t}, r(t) \rangle = \frac{1}{p} \int_{\mathbb{T}_p} e^{-i 2 \pi n t} r(t)dt.
\end{equation*}
$$
But when we try to pop out the Fourier transform of $s$ by the inner product (i.e. the familiar formula), we get
$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\langle e^{i 2 \pi v t}, s(t) \rangle &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i 2 \pi v t} s(t)dt \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i 2 \pi v t} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{s}(\xi) e^{i 2 \pi \xi t}d\xi dt \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \hat{s}(\xi) \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i 2 \pi (\xi - v) t}dt d\xi,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$
where in the case on $\xi = v$, we get an integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}}dt$ which is clearly infinite and the whole formula breaks down. I have an idea how I would rigourously prove that the rotation of $e^{i 2 \pi (\xi - v) t}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ averages out to zero for $\xi \neq v$ by splitting the integral into sums of integrals
$$
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i 2 \pi (\xi - v) t}dt = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} \int_{n\frac{1}{\xi-v}}^{(n+1)\frac{1}{\xi-v}} e^{i 2 \pi (\xi - v) t}dt,
\end{equation*}
$$
where each integral just averages out one rotation of $e^{i 2 \pi (\xi - v) t}$, and thus integrates to zero. But if this integrates to zero, then the whole integral $\langle e^{i 2 \pi v t}, s(t) \rangle$ should be zero, and the formula breaks again.
So, I am really confused about how can we arrive at the familiar formula
$$
\begin{equation*}
\hat{s}(v) = \langle e^{i 2 \pi v t}, s(t) \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i 2 \pi v t} s(t)dt
\end{equation*}
$$
for the Fourier transform of $s: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$? I know that the Dirac Delta function plays a role in it, but I don't understand how that works.

This is the Fourier inversion theorem, which can not be shortened to a simple trick. You need something like the dominated convergence theorem or similarly deep tools from integration theory to prove this.

I'm not sure I understand your question, but the Fourier transform of a periodic function
$$r(t)=\sum\limits_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \hat{r}(k), e^{\frac{i 2 \pi  k t}{p}}$$
is a sum over Dirac delta functions since the Fourier transform of the term is
$$\mathcal{F}t\left\hat{r}(k), e^{\frac{i 2 \pi k t}{p}}\right=\int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{r}(k), e^{\frac{i 2 \pi k t}{p}}, e^{-i 2 \pi \omega t} , dt=\hat{r}(k), \delta \left(\omega-\frac{k}{p}\right).$$

Note the related inverse Fourier transform
$$\mathcal{F}{\omega }^{-1}\left\hat{r}(k), \delta\left(\omega-\frac{k}{p}\right)\right=\int\limits{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{r}(k), \delta\left(\omega-\frac{k}{p}\right), e^{i 2 \pi t \omega} , d\omega=\hat{r}(k), e^{\frac{i 2 \pi  k t}{p}}$$
is consistent. But your question seems focused on addressing periodic functions, whereas the Fourier transform is also applicable to non-periodic functions, so I'm not sure the approach you seem to have in mind leads to a more general proof of the Fourier inversion theorem.
